# django create object using nested serializer and model

Tags: python, django, flutter, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Hi i am try to create 3 model objects in single post request from flutter to django restframework but i don't know how to use serializer to create object so I'm implemented many lines of code to done this but it's working fine. It's correct or not

**View.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import Booking, FromAddress, Product, ToAddress
from .serializers import BookingSerializer, FromAddressSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
# Create your views here.
class BookingView(APIView):
    def get(self,req):
        bookings = Booking.objects.all()
        serializer = BookingSerializer(bookings,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def post(self,req):
        user = self.request.user
        fromAddressData =  req.data['from_address']
        toAddressData =  req.data['to_address']
        productData = req.data['product']
        from_address = FromAddress.objects.create(name=fromAddressData['name'],phone=fromAddressData['phone'],address=fromAddressData['address'],)
        to_address = ToAddress.objects.create(name=toAddressData['name'],phone=toAddressData['phone'],address=toAddressData['address'],pincode=toAddressData['pincode'],)
        product = Product.objects.create(title = productData['title'],weight = productData['weight'],nature_of_content=productData['nature_of_content'],breakable=productData['breakable'],)
        from_address.save()
        fadrs = FromAddress.objects.get(id= from_address.id)
        print(FromAddressSerializer(fadrs))
        to_address.save()
        product.save()
        booking = Booking.objects.create(user=req.user,from_address=fadrs,to_address=to_address,product= product, price=req.data['price'],
            payment_id=req.data['payment_id'])
        booking.save()
        return Response('Success')
```

**Model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid
# Create your models here.
class FromAddress(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class ToAddress(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    nature_of_content = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=100)
    breakable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} : {self.weight}'
class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    from_address = models.ForeignKey(FromAddress,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to_address = models.ForeignKey(ToAddress,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tracking_number = models.CharField(unique=True,default=uuid.uuid4().hex[:12].upper(),max_length=15,verbose_name='Tracking Number',editable=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2,)
    payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    booking_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(default='Booked',max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} {self.tracking_number}'
```

**Serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import FromAddress,ToAddress,Product,Booking

class FromAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FromAddress
        fields = "__all__"
class ToAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ToAddress
        fields = "__all__"
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"
class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    from_address = FromAddressSerializer(read_only = True)
    to_address = ToAddressSerializer(read_only=True)
    product = ProductSerializer(read_only= True)
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = "__all__"
        # depth = 1
```

**This is API Request From Flutter **

```
Future newCourier(Booking booking) async {
    try {
      print('Clicked');
      var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(courierBooking),
          headers: {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ${box.read('access')}',
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body:json.encode( booking.toJson() ));
      print(response.body);
    } catch (e) {}
  }
```

**Flutter From Address Model**

```
class FromAddress {
  FromAddress({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.phone,
    required this.address,
  });

  int id;
  String name,
   phone,
   address;

  factory FromAddress.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => FromAddress(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    phone: json["phone"],
    address: json["address"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {

    "name": name,
    "phone": phone,
    "address": address,
  };
}
```

**Flutter To Address Model**

```
class ToAddress {
  ToAddress({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.phone,
    required this.address,
    required this.pincode,
  });

  int id;
  String name, phone, address, pincode;

  factory ToAddress.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ToAddress(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        phone: json["phone"],
        address: json["address"],
        pincode: json["pincode"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {

        "name": name,
        "phone": phone,
        "address": address,
        "pincode": pincode,
      };
}
```

**Flutter Product Model**

```
class Product {
  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.weight,
    required this.natureOfContent,
    required this.breakable,
  });

  int id;
  String title, weight, natureOfContent;
  bool breakable;

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Product(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        weight: json["weight"],
        natureOfContent: json["nature_of_content"],
        breakable: json["breakable"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {

        "title": title,
        "weight": weight,
        "nature_of_content": natureOfContent,
        "breakable": breakable,
      };
}
```

Finally Merge the Datas to One Model
**Flutter Booking Model**

```
import 'fromaddress.dart';
import 'toaddress.dart';

import 'product.dart';

class Booking {
  Booking({
    required this.id,
    required this.fromAddress,
    required this.toAddress,
    required this.product,
    required this.trackingNumber,
    required this.price,
    required this.paymentId,
    required this.bookingDate,
    required this.status,
    required this.user,
  });

  int id;
  FromAddress fromAddress;
  ToAddress toAddress;
  Product product;
  String trackingNumber;
  String price;
  String paymentId;
  DateTime bookingDate;
  String status;
  int user;

  factory Booking.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Booking(
    id: json["id"],
    fromAddress: FromAddress.fromJson(json["from_address"]),
    toAddress: ToAddress.fromJson(json["to_address"]),
    product: Product.fromJson(json["product"]),
    trackingNumber: json["tracking_number"],
    price: json["price"],
    paymentId: json["payment_id"],
    bookingDate: DateTime.parse(json["booking_date"]),
    status: json["status"],
    user: json["user"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {

    "from_address": fromAddress.toJson(),
    "to_address": toAddress.toJson(),
    "product": product.toJson(),
    // "tracking_number": trackingNumber,
    "price": price,
    "payment_id": paymentId,
    // "booking_date": "${bookingDate.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${bookingDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${bookingDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",


  };
}
```

Comment: this works fine

Comment: yeah but this back-end code repeats every object

Comment: it is better to use `.get('field')` except `['field']`. You did not consider any error handling in `views.py`. For using serializer in your response, you can create an obj, like `obj = YourModel(name=name, ...)`, then `serializer = YourSerializer(obj)`,  inside the view and give them to `Response`, `Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)`